# Schedule Agenda job to run every day at midnight

Tags: node.js, job-scheduling

I am new to Agenda jobs (https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda) and fail to understand how I can schedule a job to run every day at a given time. I have tried the following:

1. `agenda.every('everyday at 00:01', ...)` - runs only one time.
2. `agenda.schedule('at 00:01', ...)` and then `job.repeatEvery('1 day')` but without much effect.

Agenda internally uses [Human Interval](https://github.com/rschmukler/human-interval) which is inspired by [date](https://github.com/matthewmueller/date). i checked demo of date [here](http://date.js.org/) and found that `everyday at 00:00` is accepted  but could not use that very well with Agenda.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any specific hours and minutes ?

Comment: agenda.every('59 23 * * *', /*Job name or list of jobs */);

Answer (score 3):

```
//You can use something like this...

agenda.define('first', (job, done) => {
  Somefunction()
  job.repeatEvery('24 hours', {
  skipImmediate: true
});
  job.save()
  done()
})

agenda.start()
agenda.on('ready', function () {
  agenda.schedule('everyday at 00:00','first')
})
```

// This worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use repeatAt() for this purpose. Like `repeatAt('12am')`
or you can also use 24 hour format:- `repeatAt('00:00')`

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by others, I think is a bit funky as calling `job.repeatEvery()` within the job handler feels kind of out of its place.

**agenda.every** accepts `cron` format, therefore you can apply it to any defined job and run the handler according to the `cron` sequence

You have a defined job:

```
agenda.define('do-something', async (job, done) => {
  // Doing some heavy async stuff here
  async heavyStuff();
  done();
})
```

**After server initialisation** you can call it anywhere in your code to setup a repeated job. Just make sure `await agenda.start()` was already called and agenda has an established mongo connection

```
await agenda.every("0 1 * * *", "do-something");
```

This will run the do-something job and call the handler every day at 00:01am